# ma5menu moblie menu not closing

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-mobile, menu

I am using ma5-mobile-menu from https://github.com/ma-5/ma5-mobile-menu
and everything working properly however after clicking a page from menu, menu does not close and stays on on the page therefore, I have tried to close it manually by following code

```
$(".ma5menu__panel li a").click(function () {
     $("html, body").removeClass("ma5menu--active");
});
```

and it does work however it opens and close the menu twice

```
                        ma5menu({
                            menu: '.site-menu',
                            activeClass: 'active',
                            footer: '#ma5menu-tools',
                            position: 'left',
                            closeOnBodyClick: true
                        });

****
                        $(".ma5menu__panel li a").click(function () {
                            $("html, body").removeClass("ma5menu--active");
                        });
****
                    });
```

I am using angularjs and the code above is on my header directive.

anybody have idea how can i solve this issue ?